Sympy: Assume symbolic factor is positive during solve of inequality
I'm want to solve an inequality "f(x) >= y" for "x":
    from typing import Final
    import sympy as sym

    tau_S      : Final[sym.Symbol] = sym.Symbol('\\tau_\\mathrm{S}')
    tau_f      : Final[sym.Symbol] = sym.Symbol('\\tau_f')
    tau_O      : Final[sym.Symbol] = sym.Symbol('\\tau_\\mathrm{O}')
    t          : Final[sym.Symbol] = sym.Symbol('t')
    tau_on_min : Final[sym.Symbol] = sym.Symbol('\\tau_\\mathrm{on,min}')

    eq = tau_O*(-t-1)-tau_S + tau_f*t >= tau_on_min

    sym.solve(eq, t)

=>
t*(-\tau_\mathrm{O} + \tau_f) >= \tau_\mathrm{O} + \tau_\mathrm{S} + \tau_\mathrm{on,min}

Rendered: Equation
As can be seen in the screenshot which displays the equation as well as the solution, solve will not perform the division that will set "t" standing alone. Now that makes sense, given the sign of the factor is unknown.
I then tried to add an additional equation "tau_f > tau_O", to solve this, implying the factor is positive, however sympy answers with the error message:
Error message
Now I'm out of ideas, is there a way to produce the fraction for the right-hand-side that I'm interested in?

Please include complete code demonstrating your problem inline in your post and likewise include the error inline. Don't expect people to click on external links to understand what your question is and don't assume that they will take time to reverse engineer what the code should be.

Added code. However, I suspect that someone who knows the answer to the underlying general problem about assumption, does not require a particular working code sample nor will he execute it.

It is not about knowing the answer: I refuse to follow your links so I didn't even know what question you were asking until seeing the code.

Change your solve line to the following and use real=True when defining t (per OScar's comment):
>>> eps=sym.var('eps',positive=True)
>>> sym.solve(eq.subs(tau_f,eps+tau_O), t).subs(eps,tau_f-tau_O)

which gives

The order of the terms in a sum is determined by their sort order (and there are many questions in stackoverflow about changing the printed order of terms). If you only want to do this for  display purposes, you could multiply the characters in the difference by invisible Dummy symbols that, in turn, give the desired result. YMMV:


Thank you! I'm sad this reveals the next hurdle on why the result specifies that t must be smaller than +infinity and if there's a straight forward way to strip that condition.

Also, I felt like it would be a good idea to set "tau_f" and "tau_O" to positive as well, however then solve will produce the original result again.

No important enough for a stackoverflow question:
Is there a way to tell sympy to avoid leading negations if possible? I'm working a lot with differences, and fortune has it, that the order sympy prefers leads to unnecessary leading negations.

Declare t to be real.
